# How to get template id of selected article page item using Sitecore PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I wonder how can I get Template Id of selected article page using Sitecore PowerShell?

Comment: How you will identify the selected article page, Are they under a parent item? or you will provide the ID?

Comment: Page on which the script is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by simple command -

```
Get-ItemTemplate -Path master:\content\home
```

The output will look like this -

```
   BaseTemplates  : {Standard template}
   Fields         : {__Context Menu, __Display name, __Editor, __Editors...}
   FullName       : Sample/Sample Item
   Key            : sample item
   OwnFields      : {Title, Text, Image, State...}
   StandardValues : Sitecore.Data.Items.Item
   Database       : master
   DisplayName    : Sample Item
   Icon           : Applications/16x16/document.png
   ID             : {76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}
   InnerItem      : Sitecore.Data.Items.Item
   Name           : Sample Item
```

See the example here - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-itemtemplate

Answer (score 0):

Item has TemplateID property which you can access directly.

Example > `(Get-Item .).TemplateID`